# How to pass auth token to multiple http clients?

Tags: blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to pass the same auth token to my second api.  here's an example of my setup.  I can see the Bearer token in the "Host" requests but I don't see anything for my second api requests.  Why?  Am I missing something?

```
builder.Services
.AddHttpClient("Host.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
.AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
            
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<AnotherApiClient>("Another.ServerAPI", x =>
{
    x.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://another.api.com/");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

Answer (score 0):

got it working.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<AnotherApiClient>("Another.ServerAPI", client =>
{
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://another.api.com/");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler(x =>
{
    var handler = x.GetRequiredService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()
        .ConfigureHandler(new[] {"https://another.api.com/"},
            scopes: new[] {"anotherapi"});

     return handler;
});
```